# На локальном сервере работает, на веб-сервере - нет!

Tags: php, переменные, localhost, mysql

**Здравствуйте, друзья!**

Помогите разобраться в чём дело, почему на веб сервере не работает, хотя на локальном всё гуд.
**Вот этот код:**

```
$path = "img/".$myrow['page']."/*.*";
$m = glob($path);
$col = count($m);
$col = $col +1;

echo "<div class='highslide-gallery'  style='margin: auto;'>";
echo "img/".$page."/thumb"; //это последнее что выводит на страницу, дальше никак
$direct = "img/".$page."/thumb";// т.е. то, что вывел выше присваивать переменной отказывается
$files = scandir($direct);
unset($files['0'], $files['1']);
foreach ($files as $key => $value) {

echo "<a id='thumb1' class='highslide' href='/img/".$page."/".$value."'onclick='return hs.expand(this)'>
        <img src='../img/".$page."/thumb/" .$value. "' alt=''/></a>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Что в логах? Права правильно выставлены?

Comment: $page вроде бы не определена на момент вызова.
Или это только кусок кода и где-то выше определена $page?

Comment: $direct путь у вас относительный попробуйте поствить 
$direct = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$direct

Comment: ошибку бы вывели, почему другие гадать должны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извините друзья, за некорректную постановку вопроса! Вопрос решил! 
На локальном сервере версия PHP 5.3.3 а на Веб-сервере стояла PHP 4.4, поменял на модуль 5.3 в настройках Веб-сервера - ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ!